# Linux, Find > zcat > wc

Tags: linux, bash, find, wc, zcat

a have many zip files on my system. I need to calculate quantity of symbol all of them. But my command doesn't work:

```
[zola@n.korea ~]$ find /RAID/s.korea/onlyzip/ -name *.zip -type f -exec zcat {} \; |wc -c

gzip: /RAID/s.korea/onlyzip/00/node/2015-03.compare15.zip has more than one entry--rest ignored
gzip: /RAID/s.korea/onlyzip/00/node/2015-03.compare16.zip has more than one entry--rest ignored
gzip: /RAID/s.korea/onlyzip/00/node/2015-03.compare17.zip has more than one entry--rest ignored
gzip: /RAID/s.korea/onlyzip/00/node/2015-03.compare18.zip has more than one entry--rest ignored
gzip: /RAID/s.korea/onlyzip/00/node/2015-03.compare19.zip has more than one
```

But if i just zcat /RAID/s.korea/onlyzip/00/node/2015-03.compare19.zip it work fine. 
Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `--quiet` option :

```
find /RAID/s.korea/onlyzip/ -name "*.zip" -type f -exec zcat -q {} \; |wc -c
```

Beware of the `" "` around the pattern.